# Grails spring-security-oauth-google : how to set up

Tags: grails, spring-security, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have installed the below plugins

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.0"
```

Spring security core is working properly.
But I am having issues in implementing the oauth-google authentication.

The plugin documentation says we need to pass the api_key and api_secret. I have created a project in console.developers.google.com and have created the API Key and Oauth Keys, I am confused on which values to use in the application.yml.
Because as per console.developers.google.com the API key and Oauth Key are separate credentials.

Any suggestion on from where to get and how to set the below values would be helpful.

```
api_key: 'AIzaSyBjfn345tg6j0ol1e89kHMOY'               
api_secret: 'xseettDDNtjjuutrfuAFTe4d'  
successUri: "/oauth2/google/success"   
failureUri: "/oauth2/google/failure"   
callback: "/oauth2/google/callback"     
scopes: "some_scope"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `api_key` and `api_secret`

   I took those keys from console.cloud.google.com/

   API Manager > Credentials > Create / Edit the entry

   then Client ID and Client Secret are the needed values. Other parameters are paths within the Grails app itself, I believe you can change those if you want to override the default behaviour of the plugin.

But there's more ...

2. Remember about whitelisting your callback address (done on the very same panel). For local connection I set it (on Google API Manager) as 
   `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/google/callback`
3. Remember that apart of calling `grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp User Role` you need to call also `grails init-oauth2 ...` (described here - https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2).
4. Next thing I had to was to override the default login page to be able to display the link mentioned here https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2-google `<oauth2:connect provider="google" id="google-connect-link">Google</oauth2:connect>`. The default ones are here https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/master/grails-app/views/login you just have to copy them to grails-app/views/login/ and modify them.
5. Next problem was that script from point 2 didn't add `static hasMany = [oAuthIDs: OAuthID]` field to User domain, which caused the `ask` view submit to crash.

After that, the Google Oauth2 authentication worked for me.